# SimpleExcel.js function not working, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I'm trying to use SimpleExcel.js to create an Excel file. I downloaded [Simple-Excel.js](http://faisalman.github.io/simple-excel-js/) and added it to my project, and I added the script to my page. I have a separate file that uses the simple-excel functions, called download.js. This is my function:

```
function download(doctitle) {
    var xlsxWriter = new SimpleExcel.Writer.XLSX();
    var xlsxSheet = new SimpleExcel.Sheet();
    var Cell = SimpleExcel.Cell;
    xlsxSheet.setRecord([
        [new Cell('ID', 'TEXT'), new Cell('Nama', 'TEXT'), new Cell('Kode Wilayah', 'TEXT')],
        [new Cell(1, 'NUMBER'), new Cell('Kab. Bogor', 'TEXT'), new Cell(1, 'NUMBER')],
        [new Cell(2, 'NUMBER'), new Cell('Kab. Cianjur', 'TEXT'), new Cell(1, 'NUMBER')],
        [new Cell(3, 'NUMBER'), new Cell('Kab. Sukabumi', 'TEXT'), new Cell(1, 'NUMBER')],
        [new Cell(4, 'NUMBER'), new Cell('Kab. Tasikmalaya', 'TEXT'), new Cell(2, 'NUMBER')]
    ]);
    xlsxWriter.insertSheet(xlsxSheet);
    xlsxWriter.saveFile(); // pop! ("Save As" dialog appears)
}
```

The 'download' function is attached to a button; I'm just using the demo script from the simple-excel site to try to get it working. However, on the first line I get the error *"SimpleExcel.Writer.XLSX is not a function."*.

I checked the sources in the inspector and the file is there, so why wouldn't it be working in my script?

Comment: Obviously if you're getting this error simple-excel library is not available on your page. Are you absolutely sure you're including everything correctly? Could you please share your HTML with how you bind buttons and load libraries?

Comment: Actually scratch my comment. I found this thread on GitHub: https://github.com/faisalman/simple-excel-js/issues/3      XSLX function doesnt exist. Their demo is outdated or it's false advertising.